# When is it ok to use a JS redirect?

Tags: javascript, redirect, seo

I am currently working on a site where an offer on a specific set of knife has just finished. I have therefore been asked to create a JS redirect and canonical link from this page to a page that lists all the knives that we sell for SEO purposes.

I personally don't think think that this is the correct use of a JS redirect or canonical link, what does anyone else think?

P.S. I am unable to create 301 or 302 redirects at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I would say JS is pretty much never the *best* way to do a redirect – whether or not it's "okay" is really subjective, and depends on the needs and goals of your project.

If I were in your position, my first choice would be to try to explain why JS is a poor choice (no ability to do 301/302, won't work for users without JS, search engines won't know about it, etc.). If management or your client understands the drawbacks and still wants to use JS, then that's fine. I think you've done your job by presenting options and explaining the pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert on SEO and cannot tell you which solution is better for search engine ranking, but with user experience in mind, the user has entered a URL for a specific knife offer, so the best way is to show the user that this offer is expired so they know what happened to the resource they are looking for. You can show some relevant offers (and give user the option to visit list of knife offers) or redirect automatically to knife section root after a few seconds, although I prefer the former. I also do not think a canonical link is correct here as the two URLs are clearly for two different resources (one is for a specific knife set, the other for all knife sets).

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to use JS redirects when you want to redirect an url with an #anchor. Because there is no other way you can redirect such a link, a serverside redirect ignores the #anchor.

So I found a JS redirect script which we used to redirect this link to a new page (you can see the redirect in action here) → https://www.nationaleberoepengids.nl/onderwijsassistent#salaris

Since 2019 Google seems to follow these clientside JS redirects, you can find it in this Google video → https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_SDIN0KiQp4